# When is safe to reuse CPU buffer when calling cudaMemcpyAsync?

Tags: cuda

My project will have multiple threads, each one issuing kernel executions on different cudaStreams. Some other thread will consume the results that whill be stored in a queue Some pseudo-code here:

```
while(true) {
  cudaMemcpyAsync(d_mem, h_mem, some_stream) 
  kernel_launch(some_stream)
  cudaMemcpyAsync(h_queue_results[i++], d_result, some_stream)
}
```

Is safe to reuse the h_mem after the first cudaMemcpyAsync returns? or should I use N host buffers for issuing the gpu computation?

How to know when the h_mem can be reused? should I make some synchronization using cudaevents?

BTW. h_mem is host-pinned. If it was pageable, could I reuse h_mem inmediatly? from what I have read here it seems I could reuse inmediatly after memcpyasync returns, am i right?

> Asynchronous
>
> For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, host memory
>   is copied to a staging buffer immediately (no device synchronization
>   is performed). The function will return once the pageable buffer has
>   been copied to the staging memory. The DMA transfer to final
>   destination may not have completed. For transfers between pinned host
>   memory and device memory, the function is fully asynchronous. For
>   transfers from device memory to pageable host memory, the function
>   will return only once the copy has completed. For all other transfers,
>   the function is fully asynchronous. If pageable memory must first be
>   staged to pinned memory, this will be handled asynchronously with a
>   worker thread. For transfers from any host memory to any host memory,
>   the function is fully synchronous with respect to the host.

[MemcpyAsynchronousBehavior](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/sync_async.html#MemcpyAsynchronousBehavior)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get copy/compute overlap, you must use pinned memory.  The reason for this is contained in the paragraph you excerpted.  Presumably the whole reason for your multi-streamed approach is for copy/compute overlap, so I don't think the correct answer is to switch to using pageable memory buffers.

Regarding your question, assuming `h_mem` is only used as the source buffer for the pseudo-code you've shown here (i.e. the data in it only participates in that one `cudaMemcpyAsync` call), then the h_mem buffer is no longer needed once the *next* cuda operation in that stream begins.  So if your `kernel_launch` were an actual `kernel<<<...>>>(...)`, then once `kernel` begins, you can be assured that the previous `cudaMemcpyAsync` is complete.

You could use cudaEvents with `cudaEventSynchronize()` or `cudaStreamWaitEvent()`, or you could use `cudaStreamSynchronize()` directly in the stream.  For example, if you have a `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call somewhere in the stream pseudocode you have shown, and it is after the `cudaMemcpyAsync` call, then any code after the `cudaStreamSynchronize()` call is guaranteed to be executing after the `cudaMemcpyAsync()` call is complete.  All of the calls I've referenced are documented in the [usual place](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html).

Comment: So I must ensure the memcpyasync has ended before reusing the host memory buffer (h_mem), I could do that synchronizing by puting an event after the cudamemcpyasync call but, then I should make a thread waiting for this event... so I guess I could have a look at this "stream callbacks" pointed on this blog:

http://blog.cudahandbook.com/2012/09/16/stream-callbacks.aspx

Comment: BTW.
From the paragraph I excerpted I see that memcpyasync will return when the host memory is copied to a stagging buffer without any device sync. So I guess I could use a memcpyAsync without pinned memory for the first copy and one with pinned memory for the second copy (the results).